# ILookup how can I use a Where method?

Tags: c#

My lookup:

```
var myLookup = myList.ToLookUp(x=> new {x.Name, x.Job, x.Phone});
```

What I'm trying to do:

`x.Name` can contain a string of a job, or a string of a list of jobs, i.e. `"Programmer"` or `"QA, Programmer"`.

The below statement will loop thru available jobs, and match them with what is in my lookup:

```
foreach(var j in jobs)
{
     foreach(var m in myLookup[new {j.Name, j.Job, j.Phone}])
     {
          //do whatever
     }
}
```

Now, this works fine for any job Name that isn't set up with a comma, so then I tried this:

```
foreach(var j in jobs)
{
     foreach(var m in myLookup[new {j.Name, j.Job, j.Phone}].Where(x=>x.Name.Contains(j.Name))
     {
          //do whatever
     }
}
```

But that still doesnt seem to work. It just matches the Names exactly like the other way.

How can I incorporate a contains or a Where on my lookup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something like

```
string jobsToMatch = "Programmer,QA";
var relevantNames = jobsToMatch.Split(',');
var myLookup = 
    myList.Where(x => relevantNames.Contains(x.Name))
      .ToLookup(k => k.Job, x => new { x.Name, x.Job, x.Phone });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can do string manipulation before the for each:
something like : `j.Job.replace(',','');`